# Cucumber custom runner wrapper

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, junit4, cucumber-jvm

I am trying to send an email containing a cucumber report after the cucumber tests have run and the report is generated, I was trying to use @AfterClass annotation with junit but it would execute before the report had finished generating so I came accross the following blog post

I followed a short tutorial outlined on this blog
https://mkolisnyk.blogspot.com/2015/05/ploblem-solved-cucumber-jvm-running.html

The issue I am facing is, the tests are not being run and the report does not get generated.

has anyone completed something like this before? I have implemented the code in the tutorial as outlined and given the correct glue and features paths.

If I created a an empty report file everything runs and the email is sent but if I do a clean install, no tests will run and thus the report is never generated

Comment: Typically it is not a good idea to put reporting in your tests. Rather you could use the maven ant run plugin or any other plugin to send a mail after the tests.